# SQL data reader exception when querying spatial data EF 6

Tags: entity-framework, spatial, .net-4.8, dbgeography

I am using EF 6 and .NET 4.8. I have a model class `Project`:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public DBGeography Area { get; set; }
public string AreaCoordinates { get; set; }
```

In the save method, a value for Area field is generated from the Area Coordinates provided by the user.

```
var text = ($"POLYGON(({source.AreaCoordinates}))");
var polygon = DbGeography.FromText($"{text}");
```

This is saved successfully in the database.

When I try to run a LINQ query on the Area property. For example:

```
var projects = dbContext.Projects.Where(x => x.Area != null).ToList();
```

I get an exception:

> SQLDataReaderException: Spatial readers can only be produced from readers of type SqlDataReader. A reader of type EFCache.CachingReader was provided.

I am unable to proceed at this time, not sure why this error is coming up.

Comment: I solved this problem. The projects table was getting cached by EF's 2nd level cache. Turning the cache off solved the problem for me